# Meteor test only runs one test suite

Tags: testing, meteor

This is part of my project directory.

[image]

Unfortunately, for some strange reasons, all but one tests are executed, the one contained in the file `methods.transformations.test.js`.

Everything seemed fine this morning, then I ran into some issues and fixed them, and when I looked back at the test results, all my tests are no longer executed. All the files are loaded, and if I put a `console.log` inside every `describe`, I see things being echo'ed, but no `it(...)` is executed.

I'm not sure what kind of information I can provide to help resolve this issue. Can someone help?

I'm using

```
practicalmeteor:chai@2.1.0_1
practicalmeteor:mocha@2.4.5_6
practicalmeteor:mocha-core@1.0.1
```

---

### Edit

I just created a file `/test/foo.test.js` with this content :

```
describe('Testing', function () {
  console.log("Testing...");
  it('should test', function () {
    console.log("This should be echoed");
  });
});
```

And only `"Testing"` is echoed. Whereas *the exact same code* is put inside `methods.transformations.test.js` and everything is executed.

---

### Edit 2

Yes, the Meteor Testing docs say that

> The Meteor build tool and the meteor test command ignore any files located in any tests/ directory.

But my directory is only called `test`, not `tests`. Despite this, I went on and created a file called `items.specs.js`

[image]

However, the test case (i.e. the `it(...)`) is not executed.

I run my tests using `npm test` defined in my `package.json` as

```
...
  "test": "meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha --port 3100"
...
```

Comment: there's no leftover "xit" and "xdescribe" blocks?

Comment: @zim what do you mean by that? I have 3 tests (i.e. 3 `describe(...)`) and only 1 runs the `it` functions (there is only but a few `it(...)` right now).

Comment: update your question w/ the code for your tests. "xit" and "xdescribe" are ways of stopping tests from running. sometimes people use that method but forget to remove the x's to make the tests run again. thought i'd mention it in case that happened here.

Comment: @zim I do not use `xit` or `xdescribe`.

Comment: per https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html#test-modes, the meteor test command ignores files in directories called "test". it looks like methods.transformations.test.js is nested inside a "test" folder, so how are you running your tests such that the tests in there are executed?

Comment: @zim check out Edit 2.

Comment: glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While editing this question with more data, I found my issue. If anyone encounter this... well... images are worth a thousand words. This might be your problem, too!

[image: Chrome URL issue]
[image: Chrome URL cleaned]